# Will we ever need to use cache for the last job in GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab-ci

My `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
codeclimate:
  things...

rspec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec spec
  cache:
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - $HOME/somepath
```

[GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache) says:

> cache is used to specify a list of files and directories which should
>   be cached between jobs. You can only use paths that are within the
>   project workspace

`codeclimate` is my first job. `rspec` is my last job.

There are no jobs after my `rspec` job. Does this mean the use of `cache` above is redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is useless in your case.
It is also slowing the job down because it takes time to cache the directory.